# How to post status feed on Facebook page as pageadmin in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post status on my Facebook page. Status should be shown on Facebook as a page status not status from any username or from my name.

I tried below code,

```
 NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"This is a check for page post message", @"message", nil];

/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/1521177224766299/feed"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){
     if (result)
     {
         NSLog(@"Result %@", result);
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"%@", error);
     }
 }];
```

a message status was posted done page wall but that status come from my name.
But when I tried to hit same post method with page_id/feed POST Query and with same parameter @"this is my status" @"message" from graph api explorer page, it posted status from page not from me.

Please help.

Comment: u want to post a message as page in  page name as a admin

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString *accesstoken=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@","here add your page access_token"];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            accesstoken, @"access_token",
                            postingString, @"message",

                           // @"http://www.real-timesports.com", @"link",


                            nil];

    FBRequest *requestToPost = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:nil
                                                        graphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                                       parameters:params
                                                       HTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    NSLog(@"requestToPost==%@",requestToPost);

    FBRequestConnection *requestToPostConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [requestToPostConnection addRequest:requestToPost completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {


         NSLog(@"facebook result >> %@", result);


     }];
    [requestToPostConnection start];
```

Comment: this is posted as a page successfully in page admin name not ur name

Comment: if u have a any doubt i explain u

Comment: It works for few time, than I again launch the app and tried it is returning NULL. facebook result >> (null)

Comment: check your permission are granted or denied , if it is granted it working fine

Answer (score 0):

**Here is Complete Answer**

```
NSString *accesstoken = <Facebook_Page_Access_Token>

  NSDictionary*  params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"Post heading", @"name",
              accesstoken, @"access_token",
              @"Type post message", @"message",
              @"Hyperlink to your post", @"link",
              @"Add description", @"description",
              @"Image url string", @"picture",
              nil];

    FBRequest *requestToPost = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:nil
                                                        graphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                                       parameters:params
                                                       HTTPMethod:@"POST"];    

    FBRequestConnection *requestToPostConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [requestToPostConnection addRequest:requestToPost completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error) {             
             NSLog(@" %@", result);             
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"%@", error);                        
         } 

     }];
```

Comment: Please make sure your Facebook app ID have manage_pages and publish_pages in Status and Reviews. First get your page token, and then use above code to share. Ask me anything if you have any issue.